# Find column value Excel

Tags: excel

I have a data that looks like this in Excel:

```
A   17  8,5 5,666666667 4,25    3,4 2,833333333 2,428571429
B   5   2,5 1,666666667 1,25    1   0,833333333 0,714285714
C   5   2,5 1,666666667 1,25    1   0,833333333 0,714285714
G   4   2   1,333333333 1       0,8 0,666666667 0,571428571
```

I want to find a the letter representing a specific value. For instance, if I search for "17" I want to get the output "A" and if I am looking for 0,8 I want to get "G". Can anyone help me?

(In reality I want to find sort all the values in the data from the largest to the lowest and find the corresponding letter for the value)

Comment: And if you were searching for `2,5`, what would you return?

Comment: Preferably "C or B", but it does not matter that much. I can check that myself. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$4,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW($B$1:$H$4)/(L3=$B$1:$H$4),1))
```

assuming your example data is in the A1:H4 Range

When you have duplicate value that can be found this formula will return the one in the largest row number.  If you want the value in the first row number you can change the 14 to 15.

[image: POC]

### EDIT

## Option 1

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$21,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW($B$18:$L$21)/(L3=$B$18:$L$21),1))
```

## Option 2

```
=INDEX($A$18:$A$21,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW($B$18:$L$21)/(L3=$B$18:$L$21),1)-ROW($A$18)+1)
```

[image: POC#2]

The problem you had when you moved it was most likely because of your range reference changes.  The row number that is returned from the aggregate check has to be a row within the index range.  So option one keep the index range large but matches all possible rows from the aggregate results.  Option two reduces the range to just your data and adjust the results to subtract the number of rows before your data so its really referring to which row within the index range you want to look at.

## Option 3

Thanks to Scott Craner indicating the full column reference is perfectly acceptable outside the aggregate function, you could also use:

```
=INDEX($A:$A,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW($B$18:$L$21)/(L3=$B$18:$L$21‌​),1)
```

Comment: It works very well! The only problem I have is that when I move the areas to their real positions A18:L21 it stops working.

Comment: Make the first reference full column, it is okay:  `=INDEX($A:$A,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW($B$18:$L$21)/(L3=$B$18:$L$21),1))` @KGB91

Comment: Tanks! Option 2 gives me an error "there is a problem with this formula" when I try to insert it.

Comment: if you use `;` as separators instead of `,` make sure you converted them all

Comment: Just out of curiosity, would it be possible if it finds a duplicate value to first display "B" and then "C"? That is, not to display "B" two times. Your code works like a charm, I am just curious if this feature could be added.

Comment: it is possible to show all rows matching.  That should be asked as a separate question.  When you ask that question, you can place a link to this question as a demonstration of some of the work you have put in.