# Assign one value at the time from a column i Excel if the value is the same

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I got some help with a problem finding column values in Excel: [Find column value Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46019348/find-column-value-excel/46019444#46019444)

The table looks like this:

```
A   17  8,5 5,666666667 4,25    3,4 2,833333333 2,428571429
B   5   2,5 1,666666667 1,25    1   0,833333333 0,714285714
C   5   2,5 1,666666667 1,25    1   0,833333333 0,714285714
G   4   2   1,333333333 1       0,8 0,666666667 0,571428571
```

The code that I got help with basically selects A, B, C and G based of the order of the largest numeric value. The largest value is 17, that is one point for A, then comes 8,5 which gives another point for A. That works fine.

However, then comes 5. I now get B two times instead of first B and the C (the order does not matter, but I do not want to get two points for B when B and C have the same value). How can this be fixed?

(The real problem that this example illustrates is the number of seats on local boards in Swedish multiplicitets, where the number of seats for the different parties is based on the number of seats in the city council.)

Edit: Formula: `=INDEX($J$16:$J$25,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW($K$16:$W$25)/(K28=$K$16:$W$25),1)-ROW($J$16)+1)`

Edit2: Wanted result:

```
Mandate    Party
1          A
2          A
3          A
4          B
5          C
```

Comment: The link is there. No VBA, but updated with the formula.

Comment: Why isn't `5,666666667` for `A` > `5` for `B`?

Comment: Also, it is not clear to me what you want for a result?  Can you please provide an example.

Comment: Ah, true. After `5,666666667` comers 5. But when 5 comes, I get B two times.

I want the result in the edit.

Comment: If you have Excel 2010 or later, you can use `Power Query` or `Get & Transform` to unpivot the "number" columns.  This gives you two columns -- Pary and the numbers.  Then sort descending by the number column, and return the top five rows for the Party.

Comment: That is nice, but in this case I want to regenerate the numbers in my table based on the seats in the city council (I want to simulate how changes in number of seats in the city council affects the number of seats on the boards). This is why I want to improve my code a bit :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this by formulas, I think a simple way is to

- **unpivot** the original data using formulas
- Apply a `unique rank` formula to that data
- Then use `VLOOKUP` to return ranks `1-n`

The following formulas and defined names will be useful

```
origTbl     =Sheet2!$A$1:$H$4
unpivotTbl  =Sheet2!$A$8:$C$35

A8      =RANK(C8,$C$8:$C$35,0)+COUNTIF($C$8:C8,C8)-1
B8      =INDEX(origTbl,INT((ROWS($1:1)-1)/7)+1,1)
C8      =INDEX(origTbl,INT((ROWS($1:1)-1)/7)+1,MOD(7+ROWS($1:1)-1,7)+2)
```

- Fill down `A8:C8` to row `35`

In the formulas in `B8` and `C8`, the **`7`** is the number of columns in `origTbl` minus 1  (eg:  `COLUMNS(origTbl)-1`)

Any changes you make in `origTbl` will be reflected in the final table
For appearances, you can certainly hide the UnPivot table someplace.

*Note: in my locale, decimal separator is the dot*

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help!